# Is there a way to change the settings in IntelliJ and disable auto-generation of the Main class during creation of the new project?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Is there a way to disable auto-generation of the main class (class containing main method) when I create a new project in IntelliJ?

Comment: please explain how you create your project currently

Comment: Can't you just delete the class if you don't like it? It's only a once per project thing.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a project, in the left menu select "Empty Project". This will create an empty java project with no classes.

Answer (score 0):

In IntelliJ you can go to Settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and in the settings window you can choose *Editor* -> *File and Code Templates*. There you can edit you class code template as per your convenience:

[image]